# Check if an array is empty (not counting for keys)

Tags: php, arrays, is-empty

I can't find out how to check if an array is empty. I know `empty()` means 100% empty, including keys. But my array looks like this when there are (in this case) no products:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
)
```

How can I check if an array is empty like that? Preferably only for this exact "array list" because on a page that does have products I also have `[0] =>` as first value, which I filter out (but this is after I need to check for the empty array).

Edit:

```
if(empty(array_values($relatedcr))){
    echo 'empty';
}else{
    echo 'not empty';
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

get the value as array, then check it.

```
empty(array_values($array));
```

Here is a test code:

```
<?php 
$array=[1];
unset($array[0]);
var_dump($array);
var_dump(empty($array));
var_dump(['']);
var_dump(empty(['']));
```

output: **[demo here](https://eval.in/713389)**

```
array(0) {
}
bool(true)
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(0) ""
}
bool(false)
```

Comment: I added the code like in my edited post. But I get not empty on a page with products and a page without products. When I print the array I still get the same result as in my original post.

Comment: @twan  empty string have difference with empty value.

Comment: You lost me at the test code. Thanks anyway you pointed me in the right direction, got it to work with array_filter.

Answer (score 0):

This way:

```
foreach ($playerlist as $key => $value) {
        if (empty($value)) { //checking if array value are empty
           unset($playerlist[$key]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using array_filter then check for empty

```
  $b = array_filter($array1);

    if (empty($b))
    {
        echo "empty";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "not empty";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$user= [
    "name"=> "",
    "age" => ""
];
$data = array_filter($user);
echo (empty($data)) ? "empty" : "not empty";
```

output : empty